# M2 - Error : PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Return Duplicate key-sequence ['view_preprocessed'] error run any commands

Tags: magento2.3.4

Screenshot :

[image]

Error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid Document
> \nElement 'item': Duplicate key-sequence ['view_preprocessed'] in key
> identity-constraint 'argumentItemName'.\nLine: 725\n in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.php:168\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.php(132):
> Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))\n#1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php(279):
> Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('primary')\n#2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php(140):
> Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->_loadPrimaryConfig(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList),
> Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverPool),
> Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom),
> 'developer')\n#3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(211):
> Magento\ in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php
> on line 281

How to solve the error while running s:d:c

Answer (score 0):

try it:-

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code
```

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: Actually i have created custom theme from another system, i just move into my system and changes theme name like app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme. not working.

Comment: Check *.xml files

Comment: Now i am removed custom theme still getting same error

Comment: sorry, which xml file

Comment: all step follow

Comment: really sorry, what is mean all step follow

Comment: You mean :: rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

Comment: Yes i did.......

Comment: rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code && php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f && php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118628/discussion-between-himanshu-and-zus).

Comment: Remove the custom module, app/code

Comment: yes i removed still getting issue, i removed everything theme, module still getting an error

Comment: Delete view_preprocessed folder, var/view_preprocessed, pub/static/frontend, var/generation

Comment: deploy mode set:- developer

Comment: command php bin/magento s:up & php bin/magento s:s:d -f & php bin/magento c:f

Comment: when i run any command i am getting error

Comment: https://snipboard.io/gAFdD1.jpg

Comment: all custom modules deleted ??

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118628/discussion-between-himanshu-and-zus

Comment: can you join the chat pls

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118634/discussion-on-answer-by-himanshu-m2-setupdicompile-error-invalid-document).

Answer (score 0):

try it:

Go to app->etc->di.xml file and search "view_preprocessed". So you can see two same name entries and you can remove or comment this line. Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Thanks!!